# FreeBSD 10.2 "No address record" Error while downloading Xorg and Mate

Tags: freebsd

I'm having issues downloading and installing packages like Xorg and Mate gui. My internet connection works fine as it starts the download but then gives no address record error. I will attach a screenshot of the issue. https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7tVo.jpg

Comment: Seems like a dns-resolver issue according to https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/446/. What does your /etc/resolv.conf contain? Maybe two dns-serveres where the first does not resolve?

Comment: it says permission denied.

Comment: Hmm, it should be world-readable. Try become root and see the content.

Comment: I'm sorry newbie mistake. here's what it says. : http://imgur.com/X3DeYKz

Comment: No problem. :-) The third line saying '# nameserver 192.168.172.2' is commented out. That is maybe your cable modem. Try remove the hash-mark (#) and try again.

Comment: so basically its the name server's issue and not the repository's issue?

Comment: It appears so. If it is a dhcp assigned ip address you can reboot and see if if resolves the issue.

Comment: i will try that thank you :)